# Where are my breadcrumbs coming from?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I at one stage had the Menu breadcrumbs module, then the Custom breadcrumbs module enabled. I have now disabled both of them, but the breadcrumbs are still displaying. Only the Home breadcrumb is displayed on every page, and on the search results page "Home > Search > Content" is displayed.

Where are my breadcrumbs coming from since I disabled both modules?

- Search results page

  ```
  <nav role="navigation" class="breadcrumb"><h2 class="element-invisible">You are here</h2><ol><li><a href="/">Home</a> › </li><li><a href="/search">Search</a> › </li><li><a href="/search/node">Content</a> › </li></ol></nav>
  ```
- Every other page

  ```
  <nav role="navigation" class="breadcrumb"><h2 class="element-invisible">You are here</h2><ol><li><a class="active" href="/">Home</a> › </li></ol></nav>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the option to disable these are located under your theme settings (/admin/appearance/settings/THEMENAME). If your theme doesn't provide the option to disable these, you can always resort to http://drupal.org/project/disable_breadcrumbs

Comment: Thank you for that!!!
That removed the Home breadcrumb from every page. However, on the Search results page I've still got the following breadcrumbs:     Search ›
    Content

Where could they be coming from?

Comment: Did you disable the breadcrumbs using the theme settings route or the disable_breadcrumbs module?

Comment: The disable_breadcrumbs module should only be used if you are looking to show and hide breadcrumbs on certain pages/nodes/paths. Otherwise it should be removed in your templates, or if your theme allows to uncheck them in the theme settings.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal will output breadcrumbs by default if you have the $breadcrumb variable in your page templates.  It should be as easy as removing the `$breadcrumb` variable from those templates.